# gather() per grouped variables in R for specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a long data frame with players' decisions who worked in groups. 
I need to convert the data in such a way that each row (individual observation)  would contain all group members decisions (so we basically can see whether they are interdependent).

Let's say the generating code is:

```
group_id <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3))
player_id <- c(rep(seq(1, 3), 2))
player_decision <- seq(10,60,10)
player_contribution <- seq(6,1,-1)
df <-
  data.frame(group_id, player_id, player_decision, player_contribution)
```

So the initial data looks like:

```
  group_id player_id player_decision player_contribution
1        1         1              10                   6
2        1         2              20                   5
3        1         3              30                   4
4        2         1              40                   3
5        2         2              50                   2
6        2         3              60                   1
```

But I need to convert it to `wide` per each group, but only for some of these variables, (in this example specifically for `player_contribution`, but in such a way that the rest of the data remains. So the head of the converted data would be:

```
data.frame(group_id=c(1,1), 
           player_id=c(1,2),
           player_decision=c(10,20),
           player_1_contribution=c(6,6),
           player_2_contribution=c(5,5),
           player_3_contribution=c(4,6)
           )
```

```
  group_id player_id player_decision player_1_contribution player_2_contribution player_3_contribution
1        1         1              10                     6                     5                     4
2        1         2              20                     6                     5                     6
```

I suspect I need to `group_by` in `dplyr` and then somehow `gather` per group but only for `player_contribution` (or a vector of variables). But I really have no clue how to approach it. Any hints would be welcome!

Comment: Look at `tidyr::pivot_wider()`

Comment: I don't understand where the values in the `player_3_contribution` column are coming from

Comment: Ok. I now understand what your wished output is. But it has mistakes and that totally confused me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution using tidyr and dplyr.
Make a dataframe with the columns for the players contributions.  Then join this dataframe back onto the columns of interest from the original Dataframe.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
wide<-pivot_wider(df, id_cols= - player_decision, 
       names_from = player_id, 
       values_from = player_contribution, 
       names_prefix = "player_contribution_")

answer<-left_join(df[, c("group_id",  "player_id", "player_decision") ], wide)

answer

  group_id player_id player_decision player_contribution_1 player_contribution_2 player_contribution_3
1        1         1              10                     6                     5                     4
2        1         2              20                     6                     5                     4
3        1         3              30                     6                     5                     4
4        2         1              40                     3                     2                     1
5        2         2              50                     3                     2                     1
6        2         3              60                     3                     2                     1
```